# Calling helpers before template rendered

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I am building a meteor project where I need to keep all my collections non reactive. So I have removed both subscribe and publish. To show any information from DB, my helpers are calling a method in meteor.call. But in my case, the template is not being able to show the info from DB, because the template is being rendered before a anything is returned from DB. Can anyone suggest a good way to display information from Meteor.call methods in templates WITHOUT USING SESSION.

Here is my code.
My Template code

```
    <template name = "showEmployeeFromRouter">
    {{#each allEmployee}}
        <div>
            Name: {{name}}
            <br>
            Org: {{org}}
        </div>
        <br><br>
    {{/each}}
  </template>
```

Helper code

```
    Template.showEmployeeFromRouter.helpers({
    allEmployee:function(){
        //return [{name:"AX",org:"XS"},{name:"XS",org:"SE"}];
       Meteor.call('showAllEmployees',function(err,res){
           if(res){
               console.log(res);
               return res;
           }
       });
    }
})
```

Code in the server

```
Meteor.method({
        showAllEmployees:function(){
        var obj = Employees.find().fetch();
        return obj;
       }
    });
```

Does any one have a proper way to for this problem.

Comment: Was about to edit and indent correctly, but what's that last function? What is it part of? It's never called, so why is it even here?

Comment: Please check now. Thanks

Comment: If you don't want reactivity for your cursor, you can set `{reactive: false}` It will not be reactive anymore, more info: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find

Comment: EX:  `Employees.find({},{reactive:false})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did it. By using reactive var or reactive Dict. 
My Template.

```
    <template name = "`showEmployeeFromRouter`">
    {{#each allEmployee}}
    <div>
        Name: {{name}}
        <br>
        Org: {{org}}
    </div>
    <br><br>
{{/each}}
```

My server call.

```
Meteor.method({
    showAllEmployees:function(){
    var obj = Employees.find().fetch();
    return obj;
   }
});
```

And finally My helper.

```
Template.showEmployeeFromRouter.created = function(){
this.state = new ReactiveDict();
var parentInstance = Template.instance();
Meteor.call('showAllEmployees',function(err,res){
       if(res)
    parentInstance.state.set('allEmp',res);
})}

Template.showEmployeeFromRouter.helpers({
allEmployee:function(){
    return Template.instance().state.get('allEmp');
}});
```

dont forget to add reactive dictionary package.
meteor add reactive-dict